# Css except (hack) for the web browser app facebook?

Tags: android, css, facebook, browser

I have my website with responsive design and used for the size of the "vw" source in all mobile browsers the font size is the same, but in the web browser app facebook makes me sources larger than it should and would distort the design of the page. Is there any way to fix this? Is there any hack to implement css in that browser? Thanks.

For those who do not know this web browser, say it is a browser own Facebook app, and when you click on an external link in the facebook instead of opening the default browser you have on your smartphone opens this own browser Facebook app.

More info:

[Facebook app browser](http://www.stateofdigital.com/facebook-browser-biggest-browser-ignore/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `vw` for your font size is a bad idea. [It's not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) by all browsers and can lead to bugs similar to the ones you are experiencing.

The best solution I can think of (and one that is generally accepted) would be to change your elements' font size using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Another solution that is not as elegant AND more annoying to set up, is to change the elements' font size trough JS depending on the screen width. I would suggest you not do this and instead refer to the media queries.

Comment: That in case it was bad in other browsers, doing well at all, only malfunctions in the facebook app.

Comment: If you want to change an element's style specifically for facebook, you can do something like [this](https://codepen.io/leo--/pen/mAEKOQ). Please not that the size will stay static for any screen width when viewed trough the FB browser.

Having said that, using media queries is definitely the way to go here. They are super easy to implement and they would do a better job of keeping your style consistent across different break-points. This last part is super important if you ever want to do more complex styling.

Comment: I think I have not explained well ----, to see my page on mobile devices I had to use media queries for different resolutions. The size of the fonts in vw have applied it as I needed in different responsive steps to be adapting the text.

After testing the page on multiple devices and browsers, only in the browser facebook sources appear larger than normal.

I will look at the link that has happened to me, thank you very much for your time.